# How to search for specific word and exact match in ElasticSearch

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

**sample data for title**

```
actiontype test
booleanTest
test-demo
test_demo
Test new account object
sync accounts data test
```

**default Mapping for title**

```
"title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
 },
```

**tried with this query search**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "test"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

**here my expectation**

with specific word(e.g. : test ) it should return following titles

```
expect
        actiontype test
        booleanTest
        test-demo
        test_demo
        Test new account object
        sync accounts data test
```

**But**

```
got
            actiontype test
            test-demo
            test_demo
            Test new account object
            sync accounts data test
```

With exact match (e.g. : sync accounts data test ) it should return only this(`sync accounts data test`) but got all records those contains this words (`sync,account,data,test`).

What should I do to make this happen ? Thanks.

Comment: Use {query {term:{title:'test'}  }}

Comment: thanks @YJR but still its not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which ES version you're using but the following should give you an idea.

1. Using your mapping you can get all title text with `test`, including `booleanTest` using `query string` query type. Eg.

```
GET {index-name}/{mapping}/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "title",
      "query": "*test*"
    }
  }
}
```

However, for this to work, make sure you give your `title` field an analyzer with a `lowercase` analyzer filter (see below settings example). Your current mapping will not work since it's just pure `text` as is... `test /= TEST` by default.

2. There are other ways, if you're interested to know the workings of ES... Eg. You can also match `booleanTest` in your `match` query by writing a custom `nGram` `filter` to your index settings. Something like,

```
{
  "index": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "nGram": {
              "type": "nGram",
              "min_gram": "2",
              "max_gram": "20"
            }
          },
          "ngram_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "nGram"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

NB: `ngram_analyzer` is just a name. You can call it whatever.
`min_gram` & `max_gram`: Pick numbers that work for you.

Learn more about n-gram filter, the goods and bad here: [N-GRAM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html)

Then you can add the analyzer to your field mapping like,

```
{
  "title": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256,
        "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Lastly for exact matches, these work on type `keyword`. So based on your mapping, you already have the keyword field so you can use `term` query to get the exact match by searching on the `title.keyword` field;

```
GET {index-name}/{mapping}/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "title.keyword": {
        "value": "sync accounts data test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you will want to read/ learn more about these solutions and decide on the best solution based on your indexing setup and needs. Also, there may be more ways to achieve what you need, this should be a good start.